# Insert date into MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

As you can see below, I tried to insert a date like `2018-03-31` into my `event` table, but I didn't succeed. The date result of input type date. It is a `DateTime` in my database, but it is not useful for me to know the time. So, why `DateTime`? Because I want the current date if the user doesn't provide a date, and with `DATE` data type I can't.

Can you please help me to resolve this problem and understand how to properly insert a date into a MySQL table.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO event (titre,content,image,date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$connexion = Connect::getConnexion();

try{
  $query = $connexion->prepare($sql);

  $d = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
  $query->bindParam(1,$titre,PDO::PARAM_STR,100);
  $query->bindParam(2,$content,PDO::PARAM_STR,8000);
  $query->bindParam(3,$d,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(4,$image,PDO::PARAM_STR,8000);

  $connexion->beginTransaction();
  $query->execute();
  $lastInsert = $connexion->lastInsertId();
  $connexion->commit();
}
```

Comment: Append `" 00:00:00"` to the format part of the date. `date` will parse it as-is.

Comment: I don't understand why you would not be able to use a `DATE` type when the user does not provide a date. Either way you should enter what the column expects so either change it or enter it corrrectly.

Comment: $d = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00',strtotime($date)); don't work.  For the DATETIME format in my db in my sql admin panel when a declare DATE type and I select "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"  in default value there are a error "default value invalid".

Comment: when $date is "2018-03-31" , $d is "1970-01-01 00:00:00" with $d = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00',strtotime($date));

Comment: you can choose only DATE in your table structure in mysql

Comment: DATETIME work too for me. But if I choose DATE how can I do for the default value ?

Comment: If you just insert the date as `Y-m-d` format and leave the `H:i:s` part empty, it'll automatically set `H:i:s` as `00:00:00` in the database

Comment: I change for $d = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date)); but $d is always 1970-01-01 00:00:00...

Comment: sorry its because of me for the 1970-01-01 00:00:00. Before I have make a mistake if ($date = ""){...} so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the image value on the date row, and the date value on the image row. Switch the places of `date` and `image`. I think that might solve your problem. If not let me know.

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO event (titre,content,date,image) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"; 
//switch date and image like so
        $connexion = Connect::getConnexion();

        try{
          $query = $connexion->prepare($sql);

          $d = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
          $query->bindParam(1,$titre,PDO::PARAM_STR,100);
          $query->bindParam(2,$content,PDO::PARAM_STR,8000);
          $query->bindParam(3,$d,PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $query->bindParam(4,$image,PDO::PARAM_STR,8000);
```

Comment: thanks it works, I don't understand how  I didn't see this before asking question.

Comment: Then please mark my question as the accepted answer. Helps me out aswell! Glad i could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't write date in field name in query , date should be between tilde symbol(backtick escapes).

Comment: like this $sql = "INSERT INTO event (titre,content,image,`date`) VALUES (?,?,?,TIMESTAMP(?))"; ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $d = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
  $query->bindParam(1,$titre,PDO::PARAM_STR,100);
  $query->bindParam(2,$content,PDO::PARAM_STR,8000);
  $query->bindParam(3,$image,PDO::PARAM_STR,8000);
  $query->bindParam(4,$d,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

try this